# Kotlin infix function with generics

Tags: kotlin, generics, infix-notation

Try to write a simple Kotlin infix function for plus operation. What's wrong with generic type?

```
infix fun <T : Number> T.myPlus(that: T): T = this + that
```

Comment: Thx for quick reply ;) Yeah, right. How can I restrict a type for simple arithmetic operations? Extending Number seemed right design. I don't want to write a plus extension for Number.

Comment: Just for testing infix and generics.

Comment: Something like this: 
infix fun <T> T.infixPlus(that: T) : T where T : Int, T : Double, T : Float = (this + that) as T

Comment: It has nothing to do with generics. You just cannot add a Number to another Number. There is no _plus_ method defined in the abstract class _Number_, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/.

Comment: So the best way in this stupid example is to write to separate methods for each type? //

infix fun Int.infixPlus(that: Int) : Int = this + that //

infix fun Float.infixPlus(that: Float) : Float = this + that //

infix fun Double.infixPlus(that: Double) : Double = this + that

Comment: Short answer: the `Number` class is mostly useless, and doesn't support most of the things you'd want to do with it. Sad, but true. (But then, it was created long before generics were added to Java; and later on, it would have broken backward compatibility to add methods to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there's no solutions using generics for various reasons. You have to define an extension function for each Number type (Byte, Short, Int, Long, Float, Double). E.g. for Int you could do:

```
when (that) {
    is Byte, is Short, is Int, is Long -> that.toLong().plus(this)
    is Float -> that + this
    is Double -> that + this
    else -> throw Exception("Types mismatch")
}
```

Even doing that, in some cases you need to decide whether you want to truncate or round the result.

```
val n1 = 1230000000000000000L
val n2 = 123.7
```

This case (n1 is a Long, n2 is a Float) could be handled like this:

```
is Float -> this + that.toLong()
```

resulting in `1230000000000000123`

or it could be handled like this:

```
is Float -> this.toFloat() + that
```

resulting in `1.23E18`

Answer (score 0):

<s>You forgot the *operator* keyword:</s>

infix operator fun  T.plus(that: T): T = this + that

Edit:

```
infix fun Number.infixPlus(that: Number): Number =
  when (that) {
    is Int    -> this.toInt() + that
    is Long   -> this.toLong() + that
    is Float  -> this.toFloat() + that
    is Double -> this.toDouble() + that
    else      -> throw Exception()
  }

val n1 = 123
val n2 = 123.456

val result = n1 infixPlus n2

println("result: " + result)

println("is Int: " + (result is Int))
println("is Long: " + (result is Long))
println("is Float: " + (result is Float))
println("is Double: " + (result is Double))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause infinite recursion?

Comment: No, the main aim to create a custom new infix function without overloading plus operator.

Comment: You're both right. Amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Tnx for replies!

Answer (score 0):

A bit more casting safety:

```
infix fun Number.infixPlus(that: Number): Number {
    return when {
        this is Int && that is Int -> this + that
        this is Double && that is Double -> this + that
        this is Float && that is Float -> this + that
        else -> throw Exception("Types mismatch")
    }
}
```

In prev. example args:

```
val n1 = 1230000000000000000L
val n2 = 123

val result = n1 infixPlus n2
result: -1313144709
```

No exception and wrong result.

Comment: Unfortunately it's runtime only checks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the correct type of the result:

```
val types = listOf("Double", "Float", "Long", "Integer", "Short", "Byte")
infix fun <T : Number> T.myPlus(that: T): T {
    return when(types[min(types.indexOf(this.javaClass.simpleName), types.indexOf(that.javaClass.simpleName))]) {
        types[0] -> (this.toDouble() + that.toDouble()) as T
        types[1] -> (this.toFloat() + that.toFloat()) as T
        types[2] -> (this.toLong() + that.toLong()) as T
        types[3] -> (this.toInt() + that.toInt()) as T
        types[4] -> (this.toShort() + that.toShort()) as T
        types[5] -> (this.toByte() + that.toByte()) as T
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```